# KnockoutJS templates: error 'Your version of jQuery.tmpl is too old - jQuery.tmpl 1.0.0pre'

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I'm getting the above error using the latest KnockoutJS library using v1.3.0beta.
However, this is clashing with the following jquery template file:

```
//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js
```

Where can I find the CDN version of Jquery.tmpl 1.0.0pre?
Also what worries me is Jquery template's homepage states that it is no longer in development and not actively supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to locate a newer version of jQuery.tmpl on cdn.

However, Knockout 1.3 (in RC right now) includes a native template engine.  This means that you can use Knockout with templates without referencing a template engine like jQuery.tmpl.

Here are a couple of posts to help describe it until the docs are ready:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/
http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-1-native-template.html

You would not be able to use jQuery.tmpl specific syntax (${variable}, {{each}}, etc.), but the control-flow bindings along with the standard bindings are a mostly equivalent experience.

KO does plan to support [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) (the successor to jQuery templates) as well when its is stable.

Comment: @jaffa still looking for more info?

Comment: No that's fine, I'll need to grok the link you sent me.

Comment: Is it normal that Knockout still throws this error even if we only use its built-in templating functionality?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer to the question: knockout tries to use jquery.tmpl if it's referenced, even if it doesn't have the proper version.